# Copying a large file from an USB 3 disk (NTFS or EXT4) to another one (UFS/FreeBSD) is a very slow process

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, rsync, freebsd

I'm copying a large file from a NTFS formatted disk to another one,UFS/FreeBSD disk,both are removable disks attached to the USB 3 port. The file is 200 GB large and it is transferred very slowly. Why it is so slow ? I don't know where to store my virtual machines. I tried to save them on the ext4 disk because I wanted to share them easily between Linux and FreeBSD but I've realized that when I mount the disk in FreeBSD after some time it corrupts. I tried to store it on the NTFS disk but it happens the same. So,now I'm on FreeBSD and I'm copying them to a dedicated UFS/FreeBSD style disk,but as I said,the speed is very slow. How can I increase the speed ?. Actually I'm using this command,because I want to resume the uploading if it breaks at some point :

```
root@marietto:/mnt/da3p2/bhyve/Ubuntu # rsync -avAXEWSlHh /mnt/da0p1/Backups/OS/bhyve/Ubuntu/im* . --no-compress --info=progress2

sending incremental file list
impish-cuda-11-4-nvidia-470.img

2.13M   0%    9.49kB/s 6284:55:38
```

and : where do you save large files ? what's the procedure that you use to copy large files with a decent speed ? Unfortunately under Linux is not safe to use a RW ufs disk access. So,I'm out of solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I posit the problem is using rsync - its likely doing a lot of reads to work out its position and only  send diffs - ie its not the correct tool for the job.

You may be able to solve this using (gnu) ddrescue - this makes a "status" file allowing you to resume broken copies.  Its designed for moving block devices but should work just fine here as well - provided the disk image does not change while being copied.